# Examine filetype in prefix.pch

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I am thinking about that it would be a great idea for examining that the class type. In example I would like to do the following in my application prefix.pch file.

```
#if isViewController
    #import "DeviceCompatibility.h"
    #import "UIViewController+Utilities.h"
#endif
```

How could I do this.

Thanks for the ideas and your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. The point of a pch file is that it is a "Pre Compiled Header" file. It's compiled once and then that is used in every other file.

What you are asking for would require that it not be pre-compiled since it would need to be evaluated for each file. What you want is what regular, non-pch files are for.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I suppose that is not possible to import a .h file inside the .pch and then do the magic? Am I right?

Comment: No because it will also be pre-compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you check the filename somehow? In example if contains UIViewController then it is  a viewcontroller